# masonry leaves a lot of spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

I'm trying to use Masonry, but it doesn't seem to work well. It leaves a lot of empty spaces. [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPlOm.jpg)
I already tried various other ways to implement Masonry, but this one leans the most to the result. Can someone help this rookie?

Here what I think is important of my HTML/ CSS/ JAVASCRIPT

```js
<script src="masonry-docs/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// Javascript
var container = document.querySelector('#masonry-grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 33%,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});</script>
```

```css
.grid-item{width: 33%;}
.grid-item--width2{width: 33%;}
.grid-item--width3{width: 33%;}

*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.box-sizing:border-box;

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<section id="werk">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="grid">
 <div class="item">
  <div id="masonry-grid">

   <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>Manifesta 10</h3>
    <span class="category">huisstijl</span>
    <img src="images/manifesta.jpg" alt="" />
   </div>
  
   <div class="item">
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <h3>Deutsche Grammophon</h3>
    <span class="category">platenhoezen</span>
    <img src="images/GIF_1.gif" alt="" />
   </div>
   </div>
             <div class="item">
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3">
    <h3>Ghent Art Book Fair</h3>
    <span class="category">poster</span>
    <img src="images/boekposter.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
   <div class="grid-item">
    <h3>teaser masterproef</h3>
    <span class="category">foto</span>
    <img src="images/masterproef.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <h3>Mundaneum</h3>
    <span class="category">publicatie</span>
    <img src="images/Mundaneum.gif" alt="" />
   </div>
   </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **h3** Element has a margin, add this a the beginning of your CSS-Code:

`h3 { margin: 0px; }`

Your **.grid-item** has a border of 5px, change it in your CSS-Code:

```
.grid-item {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```